# Combine REGEXREPLACE and CONCAT into the same formula in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, regex, excel, google-sheets, concatenation

I have two formulas I need to combine into one. But I am getting a calculation error: "***Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but received 4 arguments.***"

Here is the first formula

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A4, "(/[^/]+)(?:/\?[^/]*)?$", "$1/")
```

Here is the second formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"",(CONCAT(B2:B,"?tag=ukos-20"))))
```

Here is my attempt

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"",(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B, "(/[^/]+)(?:/\?[^/]*)?$", "$1/")),(CONCAT(B2:B,"?tag=ukos-20"))))
```

The following is [an example in a Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FRCCS3fhPx7oUjsl3AeV5Nui7GrT4wi4ElluzFjhqB0/edit?usp=sharing), which can be copied if required with ***`File-> Make a Copy`***.

So we are performing regex on the rows and then passing that result into concat which appends a tag to the URL.

Comment: Are you just trying to keep the value in a cell blank if it is blank? Try just `=IF(ISBLANK(B4),"",CONCAT(REGEXREPLACE(B4, "(/[^/]+)(?:/\?[^/]*)?$", "$1/"),"?tag=ukos-20"))`

Comment: "If the row is blank, return nothing. Otherwise, remove anything after the final / and always ensure that final / exists. Then append(concat) to the output of the REGEXREPLACE the following string '?tag=ukos-20'"

Comment: The function itself works, but the pattern does not match the strings. Are you sure there is no `?` before `ref=`? Looks like `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"",CONCAT(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B, "(/[^/]+)(?:/\?[^/]*)?$", "$1/"),"?tag=ukos-20")))` works granted your URLs contain a valid query string. Probably, if you wish to support both `?key=value` and `ref=value` type of endings, you need to use `"(/[^/]+)(?:/(?:\?|ref=)[^/]*)?$"` regex.

Comment: So, it is not a problem of just merging 2 functions. It is either the input or the regex problem.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, I have added your formula into B22 and get a circular dependency error

Comment: I have copied your data to `A4` and pasted `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A4:A),"",CONCAT(REGEXREPLACE(A4:A, "(/[^/]+)(?:/(?:\?|ref=)[^/]*)?$", "$1/"),"?tag=ukos-20")))` into `I4` cell and all works well.

Comment: I see you are using my suggested regex fix. Shall I post the answer?

Comment: Yes, Wiktor please do. Many thanks for your help on this section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you wish to support both `?key=value` and `ref=value` type of endings, so your current regex won't help.

You may use

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"",CONCAT(REGEXREPLACE(B2:B, "(/[^/]+)(?:/(?:\?|ref=)[^/]*)?$", "$1/"),"?tag=ukos-20")))
```

Note this will remove the query string and the `reg=...` string at the end of the URLs and append the hardcoded one.

The regex matches

- `(/[^/]+)` - a `/` and then 1+ chars other than `/` and placed the result into Group 1
- `(?:/(?:\?|ref=)[^/]*)?` - an optional group (matching 1 or 0 times) matching:

  - `/` - a `/`
  - `(?:\?|ref=)` - either a `?` or `ref=`
  - `[^/]*` - 0+ chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

The `$1/` will replace with the contents of Group 1 and will append `/`.